# How to convert JSON data with dynamic element names into rows using pl/pgsql?

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, data-conversion

I need to get json from a restful service in a pl/pgsql function. (I have no control on restful webservice. It's published by someone else). I could get the json but I couldn't convert it to rows (for inserting to a table). The simplified format of it is below. Every GUID is random and I don't know their content before. When I convert it from text (with ::json) I get no errors, so it's valid json.

```
    l_json := '{"GUID-0001":{"Id":"1","Field1":"aaa1","Field2":"bbb1"}, "GUID-0002":{"Id":"2","Field1":"aaa2","Field2":"bbb2"}}'::json;
```

I tried several Postgresql json functions but each time I got a different error. i.e. when I use json_array_elements() function, I got "ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array". When I tried json_each_text() function I got "ERROR:  query has no destination for result data"

I need a resultset as the following:

```
GUID     | Id | Field1 | Field2
---------+----+--------+-------
GUID-0001| 1  |   aaa1 |   bbb1
GUID-0002| 1  |   aaa2 |   bbb2
```

Comment: Are you trying to "convert it to rows" for an `insert`?  Also, you have a nested object, so you aren't going to be able to get the result set you want with just one pg json function.

Comment: I want to insert the resultset into a table as the example resultset. I'm willing to use every json function to achive the goal, I just still couldn't figure out, because I'm new to both postgresql and json.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=34f6afbeacb8195a45c47546bdfe2107 - this could to give you a direction. But if you really new to both postgresql and json you will have more problems IMO. You need to learn some basics at least.

Comment: @Abelisto your comment was the closest solution. Because I don't have any reputation yet, I couldn't vote your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the keys using `jsonb_object_keys()` and the use that to access the fields inside the JSON:

```
with data(doc) as (
  values ('{"GUID-0001":{"Id":"1","Field1":"aaa1","Field2":"bbb1"}, "GUID-0002":{"Id":"2","Field1":"aaa2","Field2":"bbb2"}}'::jsonb)
)
select t.uid, 
       d.doc -> t.uid ->> 'Id' as id,
       d.doc -> t.uid ->> 'Field1' as column1,
       d.doc -> t.uid ->> 'Field2' as column2
from data d, jsonb_object_keys(doc) as t(uid);
```

returns:

```
uid       | id | column1 | column2
----------+----+---------+--------
GUID-0001 | 1  | aaa1    | bbb1   
GUID-0002 | 2  | aaa2    | bbb2
```

You can put that into a function that accepts a jsonb as a parameter:

```
create or replace function store_json(p_doc jsonb)
  returns void
as
$$
  insert into the_table (guid, id, column1, column2)
  select t.uid, 
         (d.doc -> t.uid ->> 'Id')::int,
         d.doc -> t.uid ->> 'Field1',
         d.doc -> t.uid ->> 'Field2'
  from (select p_doc) as d(doc), 
       jsonb_object_keys(doc) as t(uid);
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: I can't still vote, but this solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to tackle this problem is to adjust your json a bit prior to inserting and then use [`json_populate_recordset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html) to convert the json to rows.

Convert the outer object to an array in your app code, and move the `GUID-000x` value inside the relevant object under a `GUID` key like so:

```
[
  {
    "GUID": "GUID-0001",
    "Id": "1",
    ...
  },
  {
    "GUID": "GUID-0002",
    "Id": "1",
    ...
  }
  ...
]
```

I don't know what language you are using for your app code, but I assume you have some form of `reduce` at your disposal to do the job.

Once you have your data in the proper format, you can use `json_populate_recordset` like so:

```
insert into your_table
    select GUID, Id, Field1, Field2
  from json_populate_recordset(null::your_table, _your_modified_json_from_above)
;
```

`json_populate_recordset` basically takes your json and matches keys to columns defined on `your_table` and adds the values accordingly.  The catch is your object keys must match the column names exactly, and your values need to match (or be able to be cast to match) the data types defined on those columns.

Comment: I don't have control of the restful web service. It's a third party web service. (I also added this information to my question). So I can only process the json after I download it. If there is a way to alter json content, I will do it

Comment: So you have no application code that is making a call to this service?

Comment: I'm using postgresql extension https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http to get JSON. This part works perfectly. I just want to be able to convert this json data into SELECT statement with rows using pl/pgsql if there is a way.